# Debugging in IE

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer

I've got this weird bug. The progress bar in IE's bottom-window status bar keeps incrementing very slowly after an Ajax POST. At least that's where I think the problem is.

How can I tell what the hell IE is doing that's causing the progress bar to keep going? In FireFox, I would just look at the Console tab in FireBug and see what's up.

I turned Fiddler on but it doesn't pick up any HTTP requests or responses being sent.

What can I do in IE?

Comment: Perhap give firebug lite a try? 

" Firebug Lite, a JavaScript file you can insert into your pages to simulate some Firebug features in browsers that are not named "Firefox"." 


http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very experienced in Web debugging but you might try the Developer Tools that come in Internet Explorer 8. It's under the Tools menu, or just hit F12. I think the Profiler tab may be helpful. I had heard somewhere that the IE8 Tools were created to mimic Firebug's feature set as closely as possible.

Answer (score 1):

An another tool for checking HTTP requests is the [Debugbar](http://www.debugbar.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This might not help if Fiddler isn't picking anything up, but [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) is a great http request debugging tool for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem here, earnestly.  IE has a bug where it shows that a request has not yet been completed when it has.  This has been around for a while now, and I have tested my own applications against it.  There is nothing happening and there are no connections waiting for a response, yet the browser still thinks there is an open connection.

Answer (score 0):

i recently discovered this tool for earlier IE versions which can be used in combination with the IE debugger for network profiling and more behind the scenes debugging

http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/

Answer (score 0):

open IE ...thn press F12 ...here you will get many menus..to debug script choose "SCRIPT" option..and start debug...and if there is any error on page...thn u will get on Console option..also see on attach image...

[image]